# Facebook Registration widget not working on mobile Safari

Tags: facebook, mobile, registration

Is it expected that the Facebook Registration widget not work on mobile browsers?  Specifically mobile Safari on iOS 5?

I get the following error when I hit the Register button with a pre-filled form:

API Error Code: 3
API Error Description: Unknown method.
Error Message: This method isn't supported for this display type

Does anyone know of a workaround to get it working on mobile?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same here... - not iOS5 related, only iPhone related. on IPad everything works fine. It is a 'display type' message.

This was  not a roadmap issue, but a (probably) bug on facebook: reported there http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/459538657419091?browse=search_504d8f7477b589301226256

Submit your details there, and hopefully fixed soon.

Chears

Vincent YEL - Your Emotions Live

Comment: Thanks.  I've subscribed to that bug, and will update here when I've been notified about the fix.